# PNaCl ffmpeg port crashes during startup

Tags: javascript, html, ffmpeg, google-nativeclient

I'm trying to run a PNaCl ffmpeg port and run some basic commands. Unfortunately I only managed to print this error in **index.html**:

*> NaCl module load failed: Nexe crashed during startup*

I got the pre-built port from [here](http://gsdview.appspot.com/naclports/builds/pepper_43/trunk-403-ge251f37/packages/) and my Chrome version is `43.0.2357.132`.

**ffmpeg.nmf**

```
{
  "program": {
    "portable": {
      "pnacl-translate": {
        "url": "ffmpeg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`ffmpeg` file found in `payload\bin` path of the downloaded port package has no `.pexe` extension. I assume this is not a problem as long as nacl manifest doesn't specify it either. Right?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Status: <code id="statusField">LOADING</code></h2>

  <div id="listener">

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var listener = document.getElementById('listener');
      listener.addEventListener('load', moduleLoadEventHandler, true);
      listener.addEventListener('message', messageEventHandler, true);
      listener.addEventListener('error', errorEventHandler, true);
      listener.addEventListener('crash', crashEventHandler, true);
    </script>

    <embed id="ffmpeg" 
      width=0 height=0
      src="ffmpeg.nmf"
      type="application/x-pnacl"/>

  </div>

  <div id="logs"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var ffmpegModule = null;
var logMessageArray = [];
var kMaxLogMessageLength = 20;

function domContentLoadEventHandler() {
    ffmpegModule = document.getElementById('ffmpeg');
}

function moduleLoadEventHandler() {
    ffmpegModule = document.getElementById('ffmpeg');
    setStatus('SUCCESS');
}

function messageEventHandler(eventArgs) {
    logMessage('Message received: ' + eventArgs.data);
}

function errorEventHandler(eventArgs) { //Function that prints the error
    setStatus('ERROR [' + ffmpegModule.lastError + ']');
}

function crashEventHandler() {
    if (ffmpegModule.exitStatus == -1) {
        setStatus('CRASHED');
    } 
    else {
        setStatus('EXITED [' + ffmpegModule.exitStatus + ']');
    }
    if (typeof window.handleCrash !== 'undefined') {
        window.handleCrash(ffmpegModule.lastError);
    }
}

function setStatus(statusText) {
    var statusField = document.getElementById('statusField');
    statusField.innerHTML = statusText;
}

function logMessage(message) {
    logMessageArray.push(message);
    if (logMessageArray.length > kMaxLogMessageLength) {
        logMessageArray.shift();
    }
    document.getElementById('logs').textContent = logMessageArray.join('\n');
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", domContentLoadEventHandler);
```

**Makefile**

I also have this little makefile "stolen" from nacl_sdk tutorials.

```
HTTPD_PY := python $(NACL_SDK_ROOT)/tools/httpd.py

all: serve

.PHONY: serve
serve:
    $(HTTPD_PY) -C $(CURDIR) --no-dir-check
```

Comment: I am building a screen recorder using ffmpeg  and nacl, I am confused where to start would love to get your experience. I already have webports compiled but now what